# Deep neural network for recognizing spoken numbers from 0 to 20

Tags: neural-network

I want to implement a neural network that will be capable of recognizing spoken English numbers from 0 to 20 plus two or three other one-syllabic words. I'll then use the AI to control a simple game. I'm asking you for some advice. Do you think is it possible?

Is it possible and relatively easy to make it work for; one person, many people with close to native speakers accents, many people with a lot of different accents?

What data I should extract from the voice to make input for the network; length, volume, component frequencies over time, or something else? I plan to recognize each word separately.

What network architectures I should check first. Is anyone here who did something similar before?

What other challenges do you see here?

I will inform you of my progress if there will be any :)
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: too broad, neural networks can indeed be useed for speech recognition but a host of other issues need to be addressed, like feature extraction, recognition over detection and so on..

Answer (score 0):

I believe it would be fairly easy to build a neural network to do just this much more complex things have been done. I would suggest not using volume or frequency to measure because then you will train the AI to recognize things that make it specific to your set of test data and volume will depend on a number of factors like how loud a person is and how good or bad their microphone is. Frequency will depend on whether they are male or female. Adult or child. I would recommend focusing on averages of length as 20 will always take longer to say no mater how you say it and how loud you are then it will take to say one and the AI will learn based on that.

EDIT:
I would also say don't sample for volume but do test for amplitude. Try to find where in the audio the peak volume is taking place because that will distinguish between certain vowels. "One" has a peak at the start of the work with the O and Three peaks up as the end with "ee" has a higher pitch than the "th"

So in a neural network, these 2 factors would count as 2 separate neurons. 1 for length and 1 for the position of the highest amplitude in the sample.